Making a @property.setter an editable field in Django Admin Inlines
Documenting my solution here, maybe someone will have a better idea.
In my current project, we have a calculated @property displaying a value based off criteria from other fields. Up until this point this was a readonly field so there was no issue with the regular django admin interface. Recently the client wanted to make this field editable (in my actual project it is displaying a DateTime); however, the values were being pulled from two different locations based on the data type and DB constraints.
My first thought was to put both fields on the form and inject some JS to show/hide the relevant fields, but I wanted to see if this could be done with django.
Going off of some answers I found here and here, I decided to go with a @property.setter and attempt to make it work with the Admin site. Additional context is that this form was currently being displayed in an Inline. I am not sure if if was a version issue, or if it was because i'm doing this for an inline, but the def __init__() from the linked solution for populating the form did not work for me.
Inline forms ...

Here is my solution for making a @property editable in the DjangoAdmin site, which essentially gives you the ability of getters and setters in django admin.
the main issue is that @properties don't show up as fields to ModelAdmin. Putting the property name into fields=[] throws a "FieldError: unknown fields", and putting the property name into readonly_fields=[] prevents you from being able to edit it. The solution is to create a custom form with an extra field, and then tell the form what to do with that field.
Here is an example of my models that have a related field to each other. Remember this was all for an Inline, though it would seem it should work just fine for any other form.
class Model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    stuff = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class RelatedModel(models.Model):
    related_field = models.ForeignKey(Model, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    conditional_field = models.CharField(max_length=5,choices=[("left", "left"), ("right","right")],blank=False)

    value_in_left_field = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    value_in_right_field = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

      # the property creates the value based on a condition
    @property
    def current_value(self):
        return self.value_in_right_field if self.conditional_field == "right" else self.value_in_left_field

      # the setter, sets the value based on a condition
    @current_value.setter
    def current_value(self, new_value):
          # provide whatever logic you want for your setter here
        if self.conditional_field == "left":
            self.value_in_left_field = new_value
            self.value_in_right_field = None
        else:
            self.value_in_right_field = new_value
            self.value_in_left_field = None

      # this line lets you change the short description on a @property
    current_value.fget.short_description = "a different label"


and here is the admin classes to make the field editable, there are 3 parts to getting this to work:

add an extra field to a custom form
get the initial value for the field in the form
tell the form what to do with the extra field

from django.contrib import admin
from django.forms import ModelForm, CharField
from .models import Model, RelatedModel

class RelatedModelInlineForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        exclude = []
        model = RelatedModel

      # 1. add the field to the form
    current_value = CharField(max_length=200)

      # 2. set the initial value for the field
    def get_initial_for_field(self, field,field_name):
        if field_name == "current_value":
            return self.instance.current_value
        return super().get_initial_for_field(field, field_name)

      # 3. tell the form what to do with the extra field
    def save(self, commit=True):
        model = super().save(commit=False)
        model.current_value = self.cleaned_data["current_value"]
        if commit:
            model.save()
        return model


class RelatedModelInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = RelatedModel
    extra = 0
    form = RelatedModelInlineForm
    fields = [
        "conditional_field", 
        "current_value",
    ]


@admin.register(Model)
class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Model
    inlines = [RelatedModelInline]

now, in the process of this, it occurred to me that you could simply put the setter logic into the save method, which really just makes this an inline with a custom form. lol but prepopulating the field with model data is pretty cool. aaaaaand, the .setter keeps the logic close to the model instead of close to the form, so choose your own flavor. I can't really say which is better.
    def save(self, commit=True):
        model = super().save(commit=False)
        
     # logic for saving the field the way you want 
        if model.conditional_field == "left":
            model.value_in_left_field = self.cleaned_data["current_value"]
            model.value_in_right_field = None
        else:
            model.value_in_right_field = self.cleaned_data["current_value"]
            model.value_in_left_field = None

        if commit:
            model.save()
        return model

Ultimately, i guess if you were doing this calculated field specifically for the admin page the save() method is probably more readable, but if this were functionality you needed across the front and backend then putting it as a .setter is a better approach?
as you can see, the value from the form field is being saved to the correct location based on the condition.
Admin interface with Inline form
